# Regex Immediate Negative Lookahead

Tags: java, regex

I want to match `"foo 6"` but not `"foo 6</end>"`. At the moment I have the expression: `foo\s\d+(?!.*</end>)`. The problem is that it will also discard `foo 6` if there is an `</end>` tag way later on in the string. i.e.

`foo 6` Matches - **This is correct**

`foo 6</end>` Does not match - **This is correct**

`foo 6 word word word word number word number word</end>` Does not match - **This is incorrect** as `foo 6` should still match here.

The regex should allow for the 3 above scenarios to be **correct**

Comment: Hint: what does the `.*` in `(?!.*</end>)` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your explanation you don't need the `.*`:

```
foo\s\d+(?!</end>)
```

Comment: Thanks, works now. Knew it might be something simple like that.